# Upstart If Statements Executing Illogically

Tags: bash, upstart

I made an upstart script which breaks my expectations entirely.

stupid-test.conf

```
script
  VALUE="PONG"
  echo "START" >> /var/log/stupid-test.log
  if [ "$VALUE" == "PONG" ]; then
    echo "GOOD PONG" >> /var/log/stupid-test.log
  fi
  if [ "$VALUE" != "PONG" ]; then
    echo "BAD PONG" >> /var/log/stupid-test.log
  fi
  if [ "$VALUE" == "PING" ]; then
    echo "BAD PING" >> /var/log/stupid-test.log
  fi
  if [ "$VALUE" != "PING" ]; then
    echo "GOOD PING" >> /var/log/stupid-test.log
  fi
  echo >> /var/log/stupid-test.log
end script
```

stupid-test.log

```
START
GOOD PING
```

Naturally, if you execute the exact same commands in bash, it works perfectly:

```
START
GOOD PONG
GOOD PING
```

This appears to work for anything you can put in `VALUE`--I've tried integers and strings.

Comment: The equality operator is `=`, not `==`, but some shells allow the latter as an extension.

Comment: According to http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html, the equality operators are `==` and `!=`.

Comment: That said, that does fix the problem...thanks!

Comment: Also, why does that differ from when I run it as root in a tty?

Comment: My guess is that `upstart` is using `sh` rather than `bash`. When bash is invoked with that name, it disables most of its extensions.

Comment: From the bash reference you linked to: _‘=’ should be used with the **test** command for POSIX conformance._

Comment: Actually, my comment seems to be wrong, as this is not one of the extensions that's disabled in bash POSIX mode. So I guess upstart isn't using bash in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `=` rather than `==` when performing equality tests. `==` is a bash extension, and it's not available in the shell that `upstart` runs.  [Upstart runs all scripts using `/bin/sh -e`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#develop-scripts-using-bin-sh). On Ubuntu systems, `/bin/sh` is `dash`, not `bash`.

Comment: Wow.  Is this documented anywhere?  Did I just miss this very crucial piece of information?  Thanks!

Comment: It's in the `bash` man page: _= may be used in place of == for strict POSIX compliance._

Comment: If your question is where it's documented that `upstart` doesn't use `bash`, I don't know. It's just clear from the symptoms.

Comment: Thanks to your hints, I tracked down where the upstart manual specifies its shell: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#develop-scripts-using-bin-sh and updated the answer.  Thanks!